# Multiple pictures and previews in Jcrop. How to pass many id's to Javascript function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jcrop

I use Jcrop plugin (Jquery) in my app. I decide to use some ajax solution but have a problem with passing value to function. I don't know whether it is my lack of JavaScript skills or Jcrop issue.
Here is code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

            jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
                onChange: showPreview,
                onSelect: showPreview,
                aspectRatio: 1
            });

        });

        // Our simple event handler, called from onChange and onSelect
        // event handlers, as per the Jcrop invocation above
        function showPreview(coords)
        {
            if (parseInt(coords.w) > 0)
            {
                var rx = 100 / coords.w;
                var ry = 100 / coords.h;

                jQuery('#preview').css({
                    width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        }
```

Working example with one picture is here:

[link text http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail)

What I want is to pass more than one parameter to  function showPreview(coords) like:

```
        function showPreview(coords,id,size_x,size_y)
        {
            if (parseInt(coords.w) > 0)
            {
                var rx = 100 / coords.w;
                var ry = 100 / coords.h;

                jQuery('#'+id).css({
                    width: Math.round(rx * size) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * size_y) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        }
```

But error appears. how to solve that?

Answer (score 13):

```
jQuery('.image_to_crop').each(function() {
  image_to_crop = $(this);
  image_to_crop.Jcrop({
    onChange: function(coords){showPreview(image_to_crop, coords);},
    ...
}

function showPreview(image_to_crop, coords) {
  ...
}
```

Using this method you can pass whatever you want to the showPreview function (I passed the image itself but you can use an ID or ...)

Comment: You saved my life <3 The documentation of Jcrop could be way better though :'(

Answer (score 4):

```
<img class="imageToCrop" data-id="1" src="..." />
```

```
 $('.imageToCrop').Jcrop({
     onSelect: function (coords) {
         var id = $(this.ui.holder[0]).children('.imageToCrop').data('id');
         showPreview(coords, id);
     }
 });

function showPreview(coords, id)
{
    var previewElem = '#preview' + id;

    var rx = 100 / coords.w;
    var ry = 100 / coords.h;

    $(previewElem).css({
        width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * 370) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
    });
}
```

No need to loop. Just assign a class to each image you want to be able to crop: '.imageToCrop' in this case.  You an then use that class to instantiate Jcrop: $('.imageToCrop').Jcrop();

Then, you can assign a unique data-id to each image which you can pass to the showPreview() function.  That will allow you to target associated preview elements:  preview1, preview2, etc...

Comment: Can you please explain how this works with the code in the question?

Comment: OK, I have expanded the solution.  Hopefully that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the variables outside of the `showPreview` function. I reformatted the script slightly to make [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) happy.

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){

 // define these variables outside of the showPreview function
 var id = 'preview',
     size_x = 500,
     size_y = 370,
     showPreview = function(coords){
      if (parseInt(coords.w,10) > 0){
       var rx = 100 / coords.w;
       var ry = 100 / coords.h;

       jQuery('#'+id).css({
        width: Math.round(rx * size_x) + 'px',
        height: Math.round(ry * size_y) + 'px',
        marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
        marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
       });
      }
     };

 jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
  onChange: showPreview,
  onSelect: showPreview,
  aspectRatio: 1
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...

```
$('.workitem-main').each(function () {
        $(this).Jcrop({
            onChange: jcrop_target($(this)),
            onSelect: jcrop_target($(this)),
            aspectRatio: 1.336
        });

        function jcrop_target(my_id) {
            return function (c) { updatePreview(my_id, c); };
        };

        function updatePreview(my_id, c) {
            var api = $(my_id).data('Jcrop');
            var bounds = api.getBounds();
            boundx = bounds[0];
            boundy = bounds[1];

            if (parseInt(c.w) > 0) {
                var rx = 167 / c.w;
                var ry = 125 / c.h;

                $('.workitem-thumb').css({
                    width: Math.round(rx * boundx) + 'px',
                    height: Math.round(ry * boundy) + 'px',
                    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * c.x) + 'px',
                    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * c.y) + 'px'
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Note that this relies on the undocumented 'var api = $(my_id).data('Jcrop');'